# Date Uploaded filter doesn't work in Media Library

Tags: media-library

When trying to select a Media item for a field the Date Uploaded filter returns no results. This is in Sitecore 9.1.1.  Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to a content item with an Image field
2. In the Image field click Browse.  Select Media dialog box opens
3. Click the Upload Media button
4. Upload a file
5. You should still be in the Select Media dialog box.  Click the Filters drop down
6. You will see that in the Date Uploaded section it should show some number for "Today". Check the checkbox next to "Today"
7. Sitecore says "No items found"

(See screen shots)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like your index needs a rebuild. Its probably out of sync and hasn't updated with the images yet.

Comment: Hmmm.  So every time an author adds a new image we need to rebuild the entire Master index?

Comment: Also - the other filters do work.  The Dimensions and Media Type filters work fine.

Comment: Today might mean "Today, in Server Time". What timezone are you in?

Comment: I am running it on my local laptop.  So the server is in US Eastern time.

Comment: Check your `App_Data/logs/Search.log.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.txt` log file to see what search it's executing when you apply the filter. Then you can run that directly against the search provider to see what's returned and tweak it to see why it's not returning what you expect.

Comment: Ok I did that.  I see the following in the Search log: "ERROR Solr Error : ["Invalid Date String:'20190930'"] - Query attempted: [(((((__smallupdateddate_tdt:[20190930 TO *] AND _path:(3d6658d8a0bf4e75b3e2d050fabcf4e1)) AND _language:(en)) AND __smallcreateddate_tdt:[2019-09-23T16:26:17Z TO 2019-10-01T16:26:17Z]) AND...".  Sitecore seems to be submitting a Solr query with __smallupdateddate_tdt:[20190930 TO *] which is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

I opened a support ticket with Sitecore and they provided a solution.  They referenced Sitecore bug 304447.  The solution is to add the following to your Sitecore config via a patch file:

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.DateFormat" value="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"/>
```